# How to load Video from POST request using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, video, video-capture

I have REST API in Python Flask server which takes a video from the POST request and performs some emotional recognition using OpenCV and return a JSON response with the emotional data.

But the OpenCV documentation doesn't provide any way to read the Video from its string representation. It either takes webcam or a url but there is no mention about the video in string representation.

I have tried saving the video file in my server local and then using that saved file to complete my processing but this doesn't look efficient since we need to scale the feature for multiple users.

Is there any way to directly utilise the video in its string representation and process it frame by frame rather than saving it to local and using it.

Below is how I am trying to do it.

```
@app.route('/processCapturedVideo', methods = ['POST'])
        def processCapturedVideo():
        # Read as the video file from post request form data
        fileStr = request.files['file'].read() 
        # Process the video in string format using OpenCV and get the result
        return {'data': result}, 200
```

If not for OpenCV, I am open for suggestion regarding the alternatives, only that the video needs to processed frame by frame.

Answer (score 1):

`request.files['file']`  is a `Werkzeug.datastructures.filestorage`.

Documentation can be found at

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

I am not familiar with OpenCV, but you should be able to use `FileStorage`s stream API from above documentation, ie `request.files['file'].stream`

If that does not work (I know it does not work for ZipFile, as it needs a seekable file-like object), you can directly access the file object via its `._file` attribute, e.g. `request.files['file']._file`.

**Update**

After having another look at the documentation ( https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html ) and rebuilding above app locally, I am sorry to say, it looks like as `OpenCV` actually only accepts either a path or a device for input. At least the `VideoCapture` class.

Comment: Hello @J.G., I have tried using the file in "byte string", "stream" and even the "_file" format but none of it is supported by the OpenCV. I need a way to convert this file to OpenCV accepted formats or else I need a different library that reads the Video from the file format and does whatever OpenCV is capable of. If there is a different approach to send a Video file from my react-native application to the ML model such that I can process it and return the result, I am even fine with those approaches as well.

Comment: Hi Sai, I both read the OpenCV documentation again, and there it is stated you can only pass in a file name (of an existing file in a directory, not the filename of a file upload) or a device name, e.g. an attached camera. This is really odd, as almost all APIs also would accept a file-like object or buffer. I am super sorry for the wrong information I gave you. As I said, I am not familiar with OpenCV, but it really looks like you have to write the uploaded file to disk first, and then pass the path name to OpenCV.

Comment: yeah @J.G., thanks a lot for your help. I am checking out few other approaches, will keep this forum updated with my findings.